# I can play audio with aplay but sound settings show no device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.04, alsa

I started having this issue recently on Ubuntu 17.04 running on System76 Oryx-Pro.

I'm not sure when, either from restart or when waking up from sleep, my audio devices disappear. Applications such as the browser do not play audio to the speakers, but running `aplay somefile` does. When opening the sound settings menu a I see no audio devices.

I also noticed that when that happens, pulseaudio isn't running. If I run it, I sometimes get a "Dummy Device" in the audio settings, but still no sound is playing.

Strangely enough, when I connect headphones they do work, and appear in the sound settings.

After running "pulseaudio -vv" my speakers are usable again. I'm not sure when things get messed up.

The result of running `pulseaudio -vv` (~250kb of logs): https://pastebin.com/HHNfkA3i

The result of `pactl list`: https://pastebin.com/SjWS48KJ

Result of `sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp* /dev/snd/*`

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  yoav      23890 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  yoav      23890 F.... pulseaudio
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please try playing sound using `paplay` and [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959849/edit) the output of`pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio -vv`, `pactl list` and `sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp* /dev/snd/*`  to your question in a code block (`{}` button). In case you understand German [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/PulseAudio/#Problembehebung) will be helpful.

Comment: Are those headphones connected to USB? In that case, they are a separate USB audio device.

Comment: As a workaround, `pulseaudio -D` starts the daemon normally (`-vv` is just for super-verbose log output) and `pulseaudio -k` stops it, which may be necessary before.

Comment: Please reproduce the error and post the output of `pulseaudio -vv` while it occurs (so run the command, suspend the machine, wake it up, test whether there's sound, if not post the output) and `sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp* /dev/snd/*` when you don't have sound. You may redirect the output to a file with e.g. `pulseaudio -vv > error_log`.

Comment: It seems like the problem does not persist. I'll update if it repeats. Thank you @dessert